# What is 'url' when specifying the background-image?

Tags: html, css, url

Consider below code :

```
<body style="background-image:url('clouds.jpg')">
.
.
.
.
.
</body>
```

I'm not understanding what this `url()` does in above code means.

I tried with below code but it didn't work out, it didn't display a background image.

```
<body style="background-image:clouds.jpg">
.
.
.
.
.
</body>
```

Someone, please explain me the role of `url()` and where it can be used.

Comment: backgound image can also be a gradient .. so when you write url it means you will get an image file

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: The path alone without the `url()` works all fine for me. But that does not work in `try it` w3 online editor. Where did you try executing your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL stands for `universal resource locator`. In this case, basically, URL is the code, or sometimes called `path` that tells from where the resource for carrying out an action needs to be taken from. For example, if your image for the background is stored in a folder called `images` that exists in the hard disk/drive `d`, then this would be the path: `d:\images\clouds.jpg`.

Note that if the image to be taken is from the same folder where you have saved your HTML document, the image name is enough, and the complete path is not needed.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

URL is basically an address where to lock for the image. It can be a local path or some link to online storage.

URL stands for: `Universal Resource Locator`.

Answer (score 0):

[URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url) is a CSS [data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Types) whose syntax (like rgb and rgba) require the value to go in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The **background-image** property sets one or more background images for an element. you can use it under all HTML tag