# why does the background-image property need explicit specification of url() when setting a background image

Tags: html

i have started learning html and javascrip.

now i've come across something which looks odd to me, i've used the tag `<img>` like this

`<img src="pic.png" width=400>`

and then i proceeded to try and use the background-image property the same way

`<style> body {background-image:"pic.png";} </style>` with no success,

now i understand that what i need to do is `<style> body {background-image:url("pic.png");} </style>`

but my question is why? whats the purpose of the url command in this statement and why is it not necessary in the src property

Comment: You can think of `src` as being short for "source URL". The `background-image` property requires you to be more explicit about _specifying_ that it's a URL, but they're both URLs.

Comment: Both are quite different concepts that you can't mix trying to make them equal. `img` is a tag element defined under HTML specifications in the other hand `background-image` is a CSS property enclosed under their own specifications. There is no point on try to compare implementations

Comment: @DaniP thx for the answer it made it a bit more clear for me, i once briefly learned html so i came across css but as it was in highschool with a pretty bad teacher i didnt try learning it for real, i didnt know that background-image is a css property. also is it because 'style' is a property related to css?

Comment: Have you looked up the `background-image` property on a reputable website like MDN or, heck, even the official spec?

Comment: @TylerH i sure did, nowhere in neither mdn nor w3schools or other sites there is a mention of css files requiring explicitly url() function to be applied because its css and is built differently

Comment: @matanbarak That's weird; MDN shows a whole list of possible values in the Formal Syntax section when I load the page for `background-image`. Likewise the W3C spec literally *defines* it, being the spec and all...

Comment: @TylerH well yea, it is written that its a css property but when i looked as to why i need to specify the path being a url i didnt focus on it because i didnt know that its related, as i said i have just started, you dont immediately take 100% of the info you read in, you filter what is needed and what is not, my question emerged because nowhere did i see an explanation for background-image needing an explicit url mention, and especially as a beginner its not easy to know the direction to the answer, also i tried asking mates and looking it up before and i didnt find an answer

Comment: Turns out this is a duplicate after all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852068/what-is-url-when-specifying-the-background-image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is 'url' when specifying the background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852068/what-is-url-when-specifying-the-background-image)

Comment: @AdrianMole well it does seem to touch upon my question but only the first comment to the post is explaining it, even then, it is quite short, i am not sure i would have understand why u need to explicitly write url just from that comment. that post asks what does url do where my post asks why is specifying 'url' a must

Comment: tho thats up to you guys cause at this point i got my answer already, i dont think its the same question but even if you go ahead and decide it is, i dont really mind i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other background image options available, e.g. [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), so you have to be explicit about what you're providing.

Is it a url? A keyword (e.g. `none`)? A gradient?

Comment: i get what u are trying to say but can u give an example to another value the 'background-image' property can hold?, from what i saw linear gradient is a value of the 'background' property rather than background-image

Comment: @matanbarak ray did give two examples of another value: a keyword or a gradient.

Comment: linear-gradient is a background-image. background is just shorthand for specifying several background properties at once, including background-image.

Comment: @TylerH by saying examples i meant a line with background-image and a certain type of keyword or gradient as i do not know much about those types and it would help me understand it better but whatever i looked it up already

Answer (score 0):

The `url()` shows it's from a URL

Background images need a **type** (not an official term, but I suppose you could think of it like that) - and you need to specify it

There are lots of types - here are the ones I can think of

- `url()` - for an image
- `linear-gradient()` for a linear gradient
- `radial-gradient()` for a radial gradient

So if you want an image, you need to specify that it comes from a URL

So you use

```
background-image: url("kitten.png");
```

Comment: "*P.S. the background and background-image properties are kinda interchangeable*" This is not true. `background` is *shorthand* for **several properties**, one of which is `background-image`.

Comment: @TylerH yes, that is true, but you can just put the background image there, which is why I said that. It was just there for convenience, but I'll get rid of it because it might cause confusion.

Comment: The dangerous part of doing that is if you declare other items used in the shorthand before the shorthand declaration, they get overridden.